# Do browsers send cookie on Cross Site GET request?

Tags: web-application, csrf

I am able to make cross site requests because I have enabled CORS. I read about CSRF vulnerability which is caused by the fact that browser sends cookie when making a form POST request.

I tried to exploit my website to see if it works. Therefore, I tried with something simple first. I sent a cross-site GET request **but no cookie was sent**. So, my question is do browsers not send cookies at cross site GET request or is it that I did something wrong?

Comment: Are you setting .withCredentials to True in your cross-site request?

Comment: Most CSRF articles will talk about POST because usually GET does not change anything on the server, but it's certainly possible to have GETs with side-effects that need CSRF protection.

Comment: @mti2935 `withCredentials` worked. Many thanks. I think you should write an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for cookies to be sent with cross-site requests, `.withCredentials` must be set to `True` in the cross-site request.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS for more info (scroll down to the section 'Requests with credentials').